# What do you Know about some type of attacks?

Tags: https

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seguridad_de_la_capa_de_transporte

I am reading in the wikipedia, but i want to know if there is a page where i can found more details for each of the next topics, thanks in advance

Ataque de Renegociación, Ataque RC4, Ataque BEAST, Ataque CRIME, Heartbleed, Ataque de inyección ChangeCipherSpec, POODLE contra TLS

Comment: Probably better asked on Information Security SE (https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have you tried to search? Most (maybe all?) of those have pages on English Wikipedia (and you seem to understand English), let alone specialised pages elsewhere.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.